# xen to kvm migration using virt-v2v

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, migration, centos7, xencenter

I am seeing error connecting when I try to connect for conversion of xen-vm to kvm.

I am use virt-manager w/o problems.

Errors seen:

```
[root@localhost ~]# virt-v2v -v -x -ic "xen+ssh://10.61.0.47" "LAC-Venu" -o local -os /vm-images/
virt-v2v: libguestfs 1.28.1 (x86_64)
[   0.0] Opening the source -i libvirt -ic xen+ssh://10.61.0.47 LAC-Venu
input_libvirt_xen_ssh: source: scheme xen+ssh server 10.61.0.47
libvirt: XML-RPC error : End of file while reading data: sh: nc: command not found: Input/output error
virt-v2v: error: internal error: invalid argument: cannot open libvirt 
connection 'xen+ssh://10.61.0.47'
```

If reporting bugs, run `virt-v2v` with `debugging enabled` and `include` the 
complete output:

```
virt-v2v -v -x [...]
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I am seeing following errors.

```
Please also find the packages installed.
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep virt*
libvirt-daemon-config-network-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
libgovirt-0.3.3-1.el7_2.1.x86_64
libvirt-gconfig-0.1.9-1.el7.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-interface-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
virt-v2v-1.28.1-1.55.el7.centos.4.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
virt-who-0.14-9.el7_2.1.noarch
libvirt-daemon-driver-network-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
libvirt-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
fence-virt-0.3.2-2.el7.x86_64
redland-virtuoso-1.0.16-6.el7.x86_64
libvirt-python-1.2.17-2.el7.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-nodedev-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
virt-what-1.13-6.el7.x86_64
virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6-6.el7.x86_64
libvirt-glib-0.1.9-1.el7.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-config-nwfilter-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
virt-top-1.0.8-8.el7.x86_64
virt-manager-1.2.1-8.el7.noarch
libvirt-daemon-driver-secret-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-nwfilter-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-kvm-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
virt-viewer-2.0-6.el7.x86_64
libvirt-client-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
virt-manager-common-1.2.1-8.el7.noarch
libvirt-gobject-0.1.9-1.el7.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-driver-lxc-1.2.17-13.el7_2.5.x86_64
virt-install-1.2.1-8.el7.noarch
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep guest*
qemu-guest-agent-2.3.0-4.el7.x86_64
libguestfs-winsupport-7.2-1.el7.x86_64
libguestfs-tools-1.28.1-1.55.el7.centos.4.noarch
libguestfs-1.28.1-1.55.el7.centos.4.x86_64
libguestfs-tools-c-1.28.1-1.55.el7.centos.4.x86_64
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Try to install netcat, as your error message clearly states you don't have nc installed.

Comment: i am seeing following [root@localhost ~]# nc --version
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
[root@localhost ~]# 
 is it not so netcat is installed

Comment: is it checking on xenserver for nc ?

Answer (score 0):

Libvirt is trying to start netcat on the *remote* system, but it is not installed.

This is shown by the error returned from the remote system:

```
libvirt: XML-RPC error : End of file while reading data: sh: nc: command not found: Input/output error
```

To fix the problem, install netcat on the remote system.